# How to use pure CSS to select a parent node which has special child?

Tags: html, css, xpath, css-selectors

I have html like this:

```html
<a id="fixed">01</a>
<a id="fixed">02</a>
<a id="fixed">03</a>
<a href="" id="fixed"><span>001</span></a>
<a href="" id="fixed"><span>002</span></a>
<a href="" id="fixed"><span>003</span></a>
```

Now I want to select the `002` element:

```html
<a href="" id="fixed"><span>002</span></a>
```

I used `a#fixed:has(>span)` to get the last three `a` elements, but I can't continue to use `:nth-child(2)` to select the second of them.

Using javascript code `selectAll()[1].parentNode` is a practical way.

But I need to use it in XPath, so I'm looking for a pure CSS selector to get it.

Is it because `:has()` cannot be used with `:nth-child()` or `:nth-of-type()`?

How to select one of several parent elements with the same characteristics of child elements?

PS: Only use pure CSS.

Looking forward to your answer, thank you:)

---

**Thank you for comments.**

- An `id` should really be unique when used. This is used in the above code because this HTML code is just like that.
- `:has()` is not well supported, I'll keep an eye out.
- I mention XPath because the question actually came from my friend and the XPath aspect is exactly what he mentioned, I don't understand that.

After we discussed this issue offline, The conclusion is that it is currently not possible.

**Thank you all.**

---

*updated: 2022/9/30 Not possible with pure CSS.*

Comment: Not the solution, but please note that an `id` must be unique. In your case, you should change it to a `class`.

Comment: Note that `:has` is [not well supported](https://caniuse.com/?search=has)

Comment: Will you use it in Selenium? Also how *"...I need to use it in XPath..."* correlates with *"PS: Only use pure CSS"*?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short answer is **No, you can't do that**.
Pure CSS does not supports this.

Answer (score 0):

After reading the comment, and understanding the op's question, I'm posting a simple solution. And please replace your html `id's` by `class`, this is the reason that I'm not using it in my code:

```
const getSelectorByTagName = (el) => {
    const elTagName = el.tagName.toLowerCase();
    const els = document.querySelectorAll(elTagName);
    for (i=0;i<els.length-1;i++){
        if ( el === els[i] ) {
            console.log(el, els[i]); // just for you see them
            return `${elTagName}:nth-of-type(${i})`;
        }
    }
    return false;
};

const myQuery = document.querySelectorAll('a:has(span)');
/*  we know that you want the second one 
    otherwise we can loop through the array and find it
    using textNode, class, etc */
const myEl = myQuery[1]; // the 2º in array
const mySelector = getSelectorByTagName(myEl);
console.log(`The selector is '${mySelector}'`);
console.log(document.querySelector(mySelector));
```

Ok, the solution works fine! And you got a pure css selector that you need. And now I will explain how to get a parent node using css because this is the question.

If you wish to apply a different style to a parent element is possible using `:has` pseudo-class, but keep in mind that condition is the child, if the child exists, it changes the parent. At this moment, Edge, Chrome (including Android), Safari (including iOS), Opera and Android Browser support it. Global usage is 84.02%.

How to use it, as a simple example:

Css code:

```
@supports selector(:has(*)) {
  div.parent { width: 100%; height:10px; background: red }
  div.parent:has(span.child) { width: 50%; background: green }
}
```

Html code:

```
<div class="parent">
    <span></span>
</div>

<div class="parent">
    <span class="child"></span>
</div>
```

Js Code:

```
const elements = document.querySelectorAll('div.parent:has(span.child)');
console.log(elements.length); // output = 1
```